# Unity3D using normal vector to face an object in world

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So I'm making a ledge detection system that includes, ledge grab, wall slide and wall jump mechanics in 3D

my problem is that for some reason I cannot get my characters rotation to face the objects normal like I want and likewise push my character away in the opposite direction of that objects normal when I want to jump

my problem isn't accessing the normal value of the wall but what to do with it afterwards, any ideas?

Comment: If you set the `transform.position.eulerAngles` to equal the normal you get from the object do you get the behaviour you are looking for? Apologies if I am misunderstanding.

Comment: @JDormer tried it out still no luck